# Заполнение одной таблицы по данным из других таблиц

Tags: sql

Всем привет! Появилась необходимость заполнить таблицу данными из других таблиц изначально я пытался сделать, это таким способом!

```
INSERT INTO acceptUserFlight(firstN, lastN, aircompanyN, fName, fNumber, fStartPoint, fEndPoint, fDepartureDate)SELECT u.f_name, u.l_name, ar.name, f.name, f.number, f.startPoint, f.endPoint, f.departure_date FROM users u, flight f, aircompany ar, users_flight uf WHERE uf.id=? AND uf.users_id=u.id AND f.id=uf.flights_id AND f.aircompany_id=ar.id
```

Но, так заполнение не происходило и я нашел на данном сайте, способ используя INNER JOIN, я не уверен, что я верно реализовал данный вызов так как не особо часто использовал эту функцию:

```
INSERT INTO acceptUserFlight(firstN, lastN, aircompanyN, fName, fNumber, fStartPoint, fEndPoint, fDepartureDate)SELECT u.f_name, u.l_name, ar.name, f.name, f.number, f.startPoint, f.endPoint, f.departure_date FROM users u INNER JOIN AIRCOMPANY ar ON ar.ID = u.ID INNER JOIN FLIGHT f ON f.ID = u.ID INNER join USERS_FLIGHT uf ON uf.ID=u.id
```

Я не уверен, что правильно написал данный запрос. Как мне его улучшить?

Comment: Фразу insert уберите и посмотрите какие данные возвращает сам select. Он должен возвращать ровно то, что надо вставить. После того как отладите select допишите к нему insert. А как должно быть сказать нельзя. потому что вы не написали что именно должен вставить запрос и каковы данные в исходных таблицах

Comment: Select работает корректно, возвращает имя фамилию пользователя (из таблицы users), название авиакомпании (из aircompany), название рейса, начальную и конечную точки, номер рейса, а также дату вылета.(все остальное из таблицы flight). Но при добавлении Insert оно не заполняет результирующую таблицу этими данными

Comment: так не бывает. либо он должен занести данные в таблицу, либо вернуть ошибку. Умеет ли то средство, через которое вы выполняете данный запрос, сообщать об ошибках и завершает ли автоматически транзакцию после выполнения запроса.

Comment: Я использую БД для своего java web и проверив на ошибку, я получаю это  "Позиция столбца '0' находится вне допустимого диапазона. Число столбцов для данного набора результатов равно '0' "

Comment: так наверно с этого и надо было начинать вопрос. зная какая ошибка гораздо проще понять в чем же проблема. Я не работал с БД из java, но подозреваю, что вы для выполнения этого запроса используете функцию, которую можно использовать только для запросов, которые возвращают результат. посмотрите возможности вашей библиотеки работы с БД, там должны быть отдельные функции для полчения чего либо (т.е. выполнения select) и отдельная для выполнения запросов меняющих данные и не возвращающих результатов.